# My aura component is showing perfectly on preview but bugs in site

Tags: aura, experience-builder-page

Hello I created a component to create a support case from site with dependent picklist the builder preview shows this
[image: This is the site preview]

On the site the picklists don't apear
The picklist is from apex class

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getObjetOptions(String profil) {
    List<String> objetOptions = new List<String>();
    if (profil == 'Professionnel non client') {
        objetOptions.addAll(new List<String>{
            'Je souhaite participer au prochain Webinaire de présentation',
            'Je souhaite être recontacté pour en savoir plus',
            'Je souhaite m’inscrire mais je n’y arrive pas',
            'Je suis client mais je n’arrive pas à me connecter',
            'Je souhaite que ma fiche de profil soit retirée',
            'Je souhaite en savoir plus sur la sécurité des données',
            'Je ne souhaite plus recevoir de mailing et sollicitation',
            'Autre'
        });
```

Comment: Please add relevant Javascript and markup (and at best the rest of your Apex method) to your question. There's nothing wrong with your screenshot and the Apex you present here.

Comment: The picklists doesnt show in site

Comment: I finaly added the class to guest permission and that solved the problem